# Special routing for page:1 in CakePHP pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-1.2

I modified the paginator helper of CakePHP to printout the first page link without page, for example:

> myexample.com/controller/action/id/page:1 It will be
>   myexample.com/controller/action/id/ and any page else page:1 will be
>   as usual.

At this point every thing is working fine. However, I noticed that **myexample.com/controller/action/id/page:1** is still accessible as it is. I expect that it should be accessed without *page:1*. The following is the the route rule I use in config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/action/:id/:page', array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'), array('id' =>'[0-9]+', 'page' => 1, 'pass' => array('id')));
```

I need to know how could I eliminate the *page:1* to be accessible or make auto-redirect to action/id becuse this situation causes SEO problems.

**Notice: I use CakePHP 1.2.10**

**Any solution that includes .htaccess is welcomed too.**

Comment: It is not a SEO problem if you use canonical and just use the main url as url here. google will then only index the canonical url `controller/action/id/`

Comment: @mark In my app I never use URL with page:1. In other word, every pagination links set on my app does not has page:1. In Google webmasters tools, I find some reports about duplicate titles with pages such as action/125/page:1 and action/125/.Really, I don't know how Google has got page:1!

Comment: probably if you go to page two etc it will show page:1 as link. add another rule to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer on [this forum](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/htaccess-how-do-i-remove-the-same-word-from-the-end-of-a-url.2644387/#post-18512832). I have to write the following line of code at the first line of the .htaccess found at app/webroot

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)page:1(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The final .htaccess will be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)page:1(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

> **Important Notice:**
>
> If your application resident at sub-directory of your server's
>   document root, you have to add it to the regarded line of code,
>   otherwise, it will generate 404 not found. For example, supose that
>   your aplication is found at /myapp which you are accessing it using
>   `http://localhost/myapp/`, so the rewrite rule is going to be:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)page:1(.*)$ /myapp/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If we don't want the page:1 to wrongly route in 1.x/2.x we usually use another route to cover this:

```
Router::connect('/kuechen/alle', array('controller'=>'kitchens', 'action'=>'index_all'));
Router::connect('/kuechen/alle', array('controller'=>'kitchens', 'action'=>'index_all', 'page'=>1));
Router::connect('/kuechen/alle/*', array('controller'=>'kitchens', 'action'=>'index_all'));
```

Note the second one.

Then use canonical tag to make the /index/ without page:1 the canonical url. Done.

Comment: It is the same. I don't want to access using kuechen/alle/page:1 in other word, if there is kuechen/alle/page:1 it should be redirected to kuechen/alle/

Comment: thats exactly what the second route does.